# C# Deserializing HttpResponseMessage to Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, serialization, httpresponse

I'm having some problem deserializeing a HttpResponseMessage into an object.
The problem is that when the object should have deserialized all fields are null, no exceptions are thrown.

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(xml);
content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("URL", content).ConfigureAwait(false);
// Parse response
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ResponseObject));
    Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    ResponseObject responseObject = serializer.Deserialize(responseStream) as ResponseObject;

    //Possible example of wrong data
    Console.WriteLine(responseObject.Message);
}

[XmlRoot("response")]
public class ResponseObject
{
    [XmlElement("session")]
    public string Session { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Response message as a string

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\"?>
<response>
    <val n=\"session\">SESSION ID</val>
    <val n=\"status\">201</val>
    <val n=\"message\">Created</val>
</response>"
```

Have I missed something? I'm pretty new to serializing/deserializing.
Grateful for pointers.

Comment: session,status and message are values of attribute `n` of tag `val`.

Comment: Does ResponseObject not require some collection of val elements in order to match the XML?

Comment: How stupid of me... That's what I get for trying to reuse code from an older project. I'll have a go at it on Monday when back at work.

Comment: Question: I have not had time to test anything yet but I have a question.
I guess I should use a List<string> with XmlElement("val"). But how should I store the attribute for each xml row when it's beed serialized. I'd like to be able to find "session" in the list. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I solved it with the help of Eser and Biscuits in the comments.

I was trying to reuse code and did't really think about the response message having a different structure then the earlier project.

I changed my ResponseObject to this:

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public abstract class ResponseObject
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Session
    {
        get
        {
            var result = Values.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "session");
            return result.Value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            var result = Values.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "status");
            return result.Value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            var result = Values.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Name == "message");
            return result.Value;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement("val")]
    public List<ResponseXmlWrapper<string>> Values;
}

public class ResponseXmlWrapper<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute("n")]
    [JsonProperty("n")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    [JsonProperty()]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public ResponseXmlWrapper()
    {

    }

    public ResponseXmlWrapper(string attributeName, T value)
    {
        Name = attributeName;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is an optimal solution but it works.